# How to add items to empty string array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In below code i'm getting a body list as an object from com interface object. I'd like to add them my string array after that i'm planning to compare them. But i don't know how can i add them to list.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports simpackcomslvLib

Public Class TestClass

    Public Shared Sub Method1()
        Dim listBodyA As ScrNamedObjectList = Globals.SpckModel.getBodyList(False)
        Dim listBodyB As IScrNamedObjectList = Globals.Server.Spck.openModel("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TestModels\main_model\MN_SIMPACK_demo1.spck").getBodyList(False)

        Dim A() As String
        Dim B() As String


        For i As Integer = 0 To listBodyA.count - 1
            A = A.Concat({listBodyA.item(i).name.ToString}).ToArray
        Next

        WriteMessage("A elements not in B: " + String.Join(", ", A.Except(B)))
        WriteMessage("B elements not in A: " + String.Join(", ", B.Except(A)))
        WriteMessage("Elements in both A & B: " + String.Join(", ", A.Intersect(B))

    End Sub
```

This is the code where i'm trying to get object's each item to add string array but it's not working.

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To listBodyA.count - 1
        A = A.Concat({listBodyA.item(i).name.ToString}).ToArray
    Next
```

Comment: With `Dim A As New List(Of String)()` you could add elements with `A.Add(listBodyA.item(i).name.ToString)`. If `name` is a string then you can drop the `ToString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the property name from the two lists with this code

```
Dim A() As String = listBodyA.Select(Function (v) v.Name).ToArray()
Dim B() As String = listBodyB.Select(Function (v) v.Name).ToArray()
```

This will return an array with all the Name values from the two list and you don't need to know the number of items to store in the two arrays beforehand because the final destination array it is automatically created by the ToArray materialization method